# grunt-sass recursive compile in the same directory

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I have all my scss under `<project-path>/styles` parent folder. There are more folders within /styles// etc and each folder and subfolder also contains scss files. I want to compile everything via grunt task. The thing is I don't have a common output folder for css and all compiled css files should stay within the same source folders. How do I do this in grunt. I came across this

```
files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: "styles",
                    src: ["**/*.sass"],
                    dest: "styles",
                    ext: ".css"
                }
            ]
```

Will it work ?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get your required outcome with this config. So **yes** it is possible.

```
sass: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'styles',
            src: ['**/*.scss'],
            dest: 'styles',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched online, it seems that **Grunt** might **not** be able to do that.
So I tried **Gulp**.

1.Create a **Gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
sassPath = 'yourCssFolder/**/*.scss';

gulp.task('CompileSass', function() {
    gulp.src(sassPath)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(f) {
            return f.base;
        }))
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.watch(sassPath, ['CompileSass']);
});
```

2.Create a **package.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "GulpSass",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "*",
    "gulp-sass": "*"
  }
}
```

3.Install dependencies with **package.json**, and run **Gulp**.

(1)Open command line with the same folder as **package.json**

(2)run **npm install**

(3)run **gulp**

[Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/CSS) is the entire article. Please check the "**Automating Sass/Less compilation**" section.